# Will neon tetras of different sizes shoal together?

Tags: fish, aquarium, tetra

I currently have 3 neon tetras and from what i've read that's not enough. I saw some diamond head neon tetras and I was thinking of getting them but they are a bit smaller than my existing tetras, would there be an issue getting them together in a tank? and would they shoal together?

Comment: Does this question [Adding neon tetras to an existing school - Any concerns?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1610) provide the answers to your question?

Comment: Should be worth pointing out that tetras don't school, they shoal. But they should group together, loosely in numbers like those.

Comment: @JamesJenkins sort of but the answer to own question about adding different sizes resulted in death. Will the older neon tetras try and attack the smaller ones?

Comment: @Jestep good point, edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a big tank than you can have both the species because they could fight over space. Do remember that introduce new species in a group of minimum 4 (Personal experience) so that they are not bullied by other fish.